# Scala remove elements from list of tuples

Tags: list, scala

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to remove from a list of tuples elements which their first value is bigger than the second.

For example, From the list:

```
val list =  List[(Int,Int)]((1,3),(3,1),(2,2))
```

I want to get the list:

```
val list =  List[(Int,Int)]((1,3),(2,2))
```

So I used the following lines:

```
var newList = List[(Int, Int)]()
for (element <- list) {
    if (element._1 <= element._2) {
        newList ::= element;
    }
}
```

But it feels very long for scala.. Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
list.filter(element => element._1 <= element._2)
```

The filter function filters out elements which do not satisfy the given boolean condition.

Answer (score 10):

Like twillouer's and tzofia's solutions, but with pattern matching:

```
list filter { case (a, b) => a <= b }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use filter like this :

```
scala> val list =  List[(Int,Int)]((1,3),(3,1),(2,2)) 
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,3), (3,1), (2,2))

scala>  val newList = list.filter(a => a._1 <= a._2)
newList: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,3), (2,2))
```

or filterNot for the example :

```
scala> val newList = list.filterNot(a => a._1 > a._2)
newList: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,3), (2,2))
```